# present specific view by tapping on local notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, presentviewcontroller

i have 2 local notifications in my app. i want to present view1 from notification1 and view2 from notification2 . how can i do it ? and i also want to show it on any view that was before going to inactive or background state by pressing home button.

```
UILocalNotification *notif1=[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
UILocalNotification *notif2=[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
//when user tapped on notif1 
[self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
//when user tapped on notify2     
[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:notification` delegate method.

In your app delegate, implement this delegate as shown below and check if the app is currently active.  If it isn't, tell the root view controller to present your new view controllers.

Here's an example:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive) {
        ViewControllerName *viewController = [ViewControllerName new];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController];
    }
}
```

You will have to modify this a bit to handle the different notifications; however, that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: how can i know that user tapped on which notification ?

Comment: @user2096064   , to know which notification you have to check the name or key of the notification argument by looking into its dictionary: notification.userInfo